# Get country from address with the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm geocoding an address with Google Maps API and I need to get the country name by a given address. This is my code:

```
var address = "<?php echo $address;?>";
var raw;

function initialize(){

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        "address": address
    },function(results){
        raw = results[0].address_components;
        console.log(raw);
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Console returns an array with data and I want to get the country as seen on the image below:

[Here's what the console returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNWxl.png)

How can I achieve that? I've tried with:

```
raw = results[0].address_components.types["country"];

raw = results[0].address_components.types;

raw = results[0].address_components.country;

raw = results[0].address_components.types.long_name;
```

But all that returns either "undefined" or nothing.
I just want to get "Argentina" and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the array of objects is dynamic you'll have to iterate through it:

```
var raw;
var address = "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA"

function initialize(){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        "address": address
    },function(results){
        raw = results;
        //find country name
        for (var i=0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
          for (var j=0; j < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "country") {
              country = results[0].address_components[i];
              console.log(country.long_name)
              console.log(country.short_name)
            }
          }
        }
    });
}
```

initialize();

Comment: But sometimes there's more than 5 variables so maybe the 5 then is the 6, is there a way I can't avoid using this, and somehow use the types["country"] to get the country value?

Comment: Edited answer for dynamic object

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I don't know who downvoted you!

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 you can write in this way:

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
const address = "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA";

geocoder.geocode({
    "address": address
}, (raw) => {

    const cities = [...new Set(raw.map(c => c.address_components.filter(
        a => {return a.types.includes("country");}
    )[0].long_name))];

    console.log(cities);
});
```

Explanation:

- raw - object returned by `geocoder`. It is array. So we acting on this by `map`.
- in map we filtering by only these components of address that contains types including country.
- next we convert this result to `Set` to make in unique
- finally we spreading it by `...` operator obtaining simple array of strings.